# How to prevent iframe scrolling in IE (8)

Tags: html, iframe, scroll

While searching for the answer to this, I kept finding answers on how to remove the scrollbars. That does not fully solve the problem for me. I have an index.php file which I am trying to put in an iframe on my site. The index.php contains one `<div>` with a `<span>` in it.

`<iframe src="index.php" scrolling="no" style="border:0px; height: 300px; width:158px;"></iframe>`

However, when I click and drag that `<div>`, the page still scrolls (horizontally). I can only see this happen in IE8. I've tested in Firefox but I don't see it. Is there a way to completely prevent the page from scrolling if a customer clicks and drags in the iframe?

I realize this is an edge case and it probably won't happen a lot in production, but my iframe is going on a corporate web page and I would like to eliminate as many undesirable effects as possible.

I can put whatever I want in the `<iframe>` tag and in index.php but anything else on the page where the iframe is going will be off limits to me.

Index.php has the following code:

`<div id="link"><span class="link"></span></div>`

I have a stylesheet set up to make the span look like an image by using `background-image`. The background image is 60px tall but only 30px is displayed at any given time depending on whether or not the span is in focus or hovered.

Comment: What's in that span? I did a small small test in IE8 and the iframe content seem to wrap inside of iframe window and no scrolling on drag is happening

Comment: Actually I see the behavior now, it happens if span has a long unbreakable text. Interesting.

Comment: I have nothing IN the span. I'm using it as a button/link to another page. The span has a background image which is taller than the span and position of the image changes when it is in focus. OnClick it executes Javascript code to open a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to effectively cancel scroll. And since "onscroll" event is not cancelable the next best thing is to reset scroll position. Add this to your index.php (e.g into <head> section):

```
<script>
        window.onscroll = function () {
            window.scrollTo(0,0)
        }
</script>
```

on any scroll attempt (including drag-scroll) it will reset scrolling position. You may notice a slight jump, but the page won't scroll.

Comment: That's good enough for me. I noticed the slight jump but that's not a problem because it's not meant to be a scrollable area. I was mostly concerned with someone trying to select text near the image and inadvertently scrolling the iframe to a point where the image is partially or not at all visible.